# Find letters in a column which are unique in comparison to several other columns, count them in segments and print their position

Tags: r

I am trying to prepare an input file for the Skov method https://github.com/LauritsSkov/Introgression-detection to look at ghost ancestry in dolphin populations.

I have a dataset looking like this:

```
chr  pos ind0 ind1 ind2 ind3 ind4 ind5 ind6 ind7 ind8 ind9 ind10

MRVK01001299.1 972    C    C    T    N    C    C    T    N    N    C     C

MRVK01001299.1 973    G    G    G    N    G    G    G    N    N    G     G

MRVK01001299.1 997    C    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T     T

MRVK01001299.1 999    A    T    T    N    T    T    T    T    T    T     T

MRVK01001299.1 1018   A    C    T    N    T    C    C    T    T    T     T

MRVK01001299.1 1086   A    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T    T     T

MRVK01001299.1 2125   C    C    T    N    C    C    T    N    N    C     C

MRVK01001299.1 2456   G    G    G    N    G    G    G    N    N    G     G
```

The data is the scaffold, position and then the allele (A, T, C, G, N) found in each of the individuals. I am comparing one particular individual (ind0) to the others to see if he has clusters of private alleles. If so, this may indicate he has ancestry from a population we have not sampled (ghost population). The chrm and pos columns indicate the position in the bottlenose dolphin reference genome.

This is the result of `dput()` on the first 8 rows (out of 43,500) of my dataset for the first 3 individuals (there are 22 individuals):

```
structure(list(chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "MRVK01001299.1", class = "factor"), pos = c(1972L, 1973L, 2097L, 8281L, 8357L, 8653L, 8746L, 9255L), ind0 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "N", "T" ), class = "factor"), ind1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "N", "T"), class = "factor"), ind2 = structure(c(5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "N", "T"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 8L))
```

Note that the table above is an example including private allele but the first rows do not include any.

I would like to identify the position (`pos`) for which letters are found uniquely in `ind0`. “N”s would not be counted as a different letters. So for example, we would have a unique value for position 997, 999 and 1086.

Then, I would like to count how many times `ind0` has a private letters in series of 1000 for the position (`pos`) column. And print the positions of the private alleles for each bins. So this would be (output file needed):

```
0 2 997, 999

1000 1 1086

2000 0

etc
```

Because we have two positions (positions 997, 999) with a unique value for `ind0` between 0 and 1000, 1 between 1000 and 2000 (position 1086), 0 between 2000 and 3000. The furthest value will be above 20,000,000.

@zx87754 provided the below code, and I would like to add “`print`” the positions of the private alleles. I did not find help on the forums, apart that the print or awk functions may be helpful here.

Identify for which SNPs `ind0` has a private allele - "N"s do not count as a different allele as missing data:

```
res1 <- df1[ rowSums(df1$ind0 == df1 [, -c(1:3)]) == 0 &
               apply(df1 [, -c(1:3)], 1, function(i) length(unique(i[ i != "N" ]))) == 1, ]

Count the number of positions with a private allele for ind0 in bins of 1000 bp:

res2<-table(cut(res1$pos, c(seq(0, 23092000, by=1000))))
```

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

```r
#DATA
set.seed(42)
d = data.frame(chr = "A",
               pos = 1:20,
               ind0 = sample(x = c("A", "C", "T", "G", "N"),
                             size = 20,
                             replace = TRUE,
                             prob = c(.24, .24, .24, .24, .04)))
d$ind1 = d$ind0
d$ind1[sample(1:20, 5)] = sample(x = c("A", "C", "T", "G", "N"),
                                 size = 5,
                                 replace = TRUE,
                                 prob = c(.24, .24, .24, .24, .04))
d$ind2 = d$ind1


# Subset the columns ind1 thorugh the end and get the unique value for each row
all_rows = apply(X = d[!colnames(d) %in% c("chr", "pos", "ind0")],
                 MARGIN = 1,
                 FUN = function(x){
                     if (length(unique(x)) == 1 & x[1] != "N") {
                         x[1]
                     } else {
                         NA
                     }
                 })

# Identify the row index where ind0 differs from all_rows
inds = which(d[, "ind0"] != all_rows & !is.na(d[, "ind0"]))

# Use the inds to extract the data that you need
d$pos[inds]
#> [1]  5 19 20
d[inds,]
#>    chr pos ind0 ind1 ind2
#> 5    A   5    G    A    A
#> 19   A  19    T    C    C
#> 20   A  20    G    A    A
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For binning and counting, you could do

```r
positions = d$pos[inds]
bins = seq(0, 20, 5)
ans = aggregate(list(pos = positions), list(b = cut(positions, bins)), c)
ans$n = lengths(ans$pos)
ans
#        b    pos n
#1   (0,5]      5 1
#2 (15,20] 19, 20 2
```

Comment: Many thanks, then I would like the count of private sites per bins of 1000 and the positions printed. I have edited my post above and indicate which is the output file needed.

Comment: Many thanks. I haven't been successful to modify the following. There are 22 individuals, if individuals has a letter for example "A" and all the other have either "T" or "N", it would still be private (not only if there is one "N"). I also would like to print the bins with count 0. So all the bins (in my case between 0 and 20000000, with steps of 1000) would appear with a count of private position (including 0) and if there are private positions, the positions would be printed next to the count.